# Finding the interval of convergence using the ratio test

Tags: calculus, power-series, confidence-interval

I found that the Taylor series for $h(t)=\ln(t)$ centered at $t_0=1$ is
$$\sum^\infty_{n=0}(-1)^n\frac{1}{n+1}(t-1)^{n+1}$$
Now I want to find the interval of confidence for this series, so I use the ratio test:
\begin{align}
&\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left|\frac{(-1)^{n+1}\frac{1}{n+2}(t-1)^{n+2}}{(-1)^n\frac{1}{n+1}(t-1)^{n+1}}\right|\\
=&|t-1|\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left|(-1)\frac{n+1}{n+2}\right|\\
=&|t-1|\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}|-1|\\
=&|t-1|=L
\end{align}
The series converges when $L<1$, so we get the interval $0<t<2$. However, this is incorrect. I was told that the correct interval is $0<t\leq2$.

Why is the interval inclusive of $2$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The series converges for $|t-1| <1$ and diverges for $|t-1| >1$. For $|t-1|=1$ you have to check separately for convergence. When $t=0$ the series is divergent by comparison with the harmonic series. For $t=2$ it is convergent by the Alternating Series Test.

In general  the ratio test does not say anything about the convergence of $\sum a_n (t-c)^{n}$ when $|t-c|=L$ where $L$ is the number you get from the Ratio Test.